# How to pick the rigth Data in R?

Tags: r

I have a sample data set with demand data for 8891 different products in 8 countries over 3 years. I would like to run forecast procedures for the individual products and countries and compare them with each other. I know how to solve the problem theoretically, but not how to write the code.
This works for single examples:

```
# Take France and Product_1875
data = data_tidy_demand %>%
    filter(product_id %in% "Product_1875") %>%
    filter(country_id %in% "FR") %>%
    group_by(country_id)

library(fpp)
library(forecast)

test_forcast = meanf(data$demand, h =5)

test_forcast
```

I then tried to do the same for all 8 countries at the same time, but failed because of the For loop.
Why does this not work for the two countries mentioned?

```
# For loop: Take GB & FR
i = c("FR", "GB")

forecast_df = data_tidy_demand %>%
    for (i in country_id) {
        filter(country_id %in% i) %>%
        meanf(data$demand, h =5)
    }
```

I watch Udemy courses, but they can't help me with this specific problem.
I hope someone understands the mistake I made.
Thanks a lot, dear community!

Comment: What is output of `test_forcast`? Is it one number? Try `data_tidy_demand %>%
  group_by(product_id, country_id) %>%
  summarise(test_forcast = test_forcast(demand, h = 5))
  `

Comment: Thank you for your reply:
I don't get an output of `test_forecast` with my idea. I tried your idea, but it doesn't work either "Mistake in test_forcast(demand, h = 5) : 
  could not find a function "test_forcast" "
Do i have to change my `test_forcast = meanf(data$demand, h =5)` first?

Comment: Now I understand the function `summarise`: Problem is that I get several values and therefore need more than one new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `meanf` returns an object of class `forecast`, we can keep the data in a list.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

forecast_df <- data_tidy_demand %>% 
                 group_by(product_id, country_id) %>% 
                 summarise(test_forcast = list(meanf(demand, h = 5)))
```

Comment: Sorry, now I'm lost:  "Mistake: Input must be list of vectors".
`data_tidy_demand` is a dataframe with columns: `product_id`, `country_id`, `date`, `demand`. I thought that a column is automatically a vector?

Comment: It works: I get a column `test_forecast` with lists - you are awesome!
Is it possible to split the information of the lists into new columns? Do you have any advice on that? Now I have 18,505 entries in three columns: `product_id`, `country_id`, `test_forcast`.

Comment: Actually they should be available in `forecast_df$test_forcast[[1]]$lower`, `forecast_df$test_forcast[[1]]$upper`.

Comment: I was thinking about a way like that, because I need to use it as an .xlsx later. But again a problem with a for loop:

`forecast_df2 = forecast_df %>%
    for(i in x) {
    mutate(first_period = forecast_df$test_forcast[[i]]$mean[1],
           second_period = forecast_df$test_forcast[[i]]$mean[2],
           third_period = forecast_df$test_forcast[[i]]$mean[3],
           fourth_period = forecast_df$test_forcast[[i]]$mean[4],
           fifth_period = forecast_df$test_forcast[[i]]$mean[5])}`

Comment: Finally I found a better way:
`x = c(seq(1, 18505, length.out=18505))`,

`for(i in x) {forecast_df$first_period[i] = round(forecast_df$test_forcast[[i]]$mean[1], digits = 4)} `